# ファイル名がSJISでエンコーディングされているFTPサーバからwgetで日本語名ファイルをダウンロードしたい

Tags: ftp

環境: Ubuntu 14.04

こういったようにwgetでFTPからファイルをダウンロードしようとしました。

```
wget --user=<USER> --password=<PASS>  "ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt"

<< 日本語ファイル名.txt: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

しかし上記のエラーになってしまいます。

`--no-remove-listing`でリストファイルを確認してみると

```
wget --user=<USER> --password=<PASS> --no-remove-listing "ftp://<DOMAIN>"
cat .listing | nkf --guess
<< Shift_JIS (CRLF)
```

ファイルはSJISエンコーディングされていました。そこでファイル名をSJISで指定すれば
できるのかなと思い、下記のようなコマンドも試してみましたが、ダメでした。

```
wget --user=<USER> --password=<PASS> "`echo ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt | nkf -s`"
wget --user=<USER> --password=<PASS> --remote-encoding=Shift_JIS "ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt"
wget --user=<USER> --password=<PASS> --remote-encoding=sjis "ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt"
wget --user=<USER> --password=<PASS> --remote-encoding=cp932 "ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt"
```

何か方法はないでしょうか？

**暫定解決？**

コメントで指摘いただいた通り、echoに`-n`をつけるとダウンロードできました。
    wget --user= --password= "`echo -n ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt | nkf -s`"
ただし、特定の日本語が含まれているとエラーになるようでした。

〇 日本語ファイル名.txt
✕ 日本語ファーイル名.txt

Windows版のwgetだっとnkfで文字コード変換をしなくてもダウンロードできた(ーが含まれていても)ので、とりあえずこれで運用しようと思います。
https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Comment: `man wget`したところ、`--remote-encoding`というオプションがあるようです。

Comment: `--remote-encoding`も試してみたのですがダメでした。`--remote-encoding`で試した内容も本文に追加しました。

Comment: `--remote-encoding`はファイルコンテンツに対する操作のようです。

Comment: echo に -n を付けてみては?

Comment: 投稿時の編集によるtypoかもしれませんが、`echo ftp://<DOMAIN>日本語ファイル名.txt | nkf -s`ではなくて`echo ftp://<DOMAIN>/日本語ファイル名.txt | nkf -s`が正しいのでは？　それから上のコメントの補足として`printf`を使ってもよさそうです。